# Error running imported functions when executing with Node-Schedule

Tags: node.js, cron, node-schedule

I am using node-schedule to run some recurring cron jobs. These jobs run every day and execute another imported function. The problem I'm having is the imported functions aren't recognized as functions when the cron job is executed.

```
const { getJobs, runBot } = require('c:/Users/carjames/OneDrive - Cisco/Documents/Code/Barton-Bot-Backend/utils/bot/botJobActions');

const createCron = (job) =>{
    debug('[+] Scheduling Job')
    const day = sevenDaysBefore(job.date, true)
    const startDate = new Date(job.botStartDate ? job.botStartDate : sevenDaysBefore(job.date, true))
    const startTime = new Date(`09/19/2000 ${job.botStartTime ? job.botStartTime : '6:05 AM'}`)

    startDate.setHours(startTime.getHours())
    startDate.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes())
    const jobb = schedule.scheduleJob(job.date, startDate, async function(){
        debug('[+] Starting Job...')
        await runBot([job])
    })
    debug('[+] Job Scheduled')
}
```

This is the runBot function that is being imported.

```
const runBot = async (todayJobs) =>{
    await mongoConnect(process.env.DB_PWORD)
    
    for(const job of todayJobs){
        debug('[+] Decrypting ClubPassword...')
        const clubPassword = decryptToken(job.clubPassword.token, job.clubPassword.iv)
        const user = job.user

        if(job.proxy){
            debug('[+] Proxy Enabled')
            const proxyConfig = await getProxyConfig(user)
            if(proxyConfig.status === "no proxy"){
                debug("[-] Proxy Config Retrival Error/Running Without Proxy")
            }
            await startBot(member=job.member?job.member : null, proxy=proxyConfig.status === 'success'?proxyConfig:null, job.clubUsername, clubPassword, job.startTime, job.endTime, job.date, job.courseList, job.id)
            // await console.log(member=job.member?job.member : null, proxy=proxyConfig.status === 'success'?proxyConfig:null, job.clubUsername, clubPassword, job.startTime, job.endTime, job.courseList, job.id)
        }else{
            await startBot(member=job.member?job.member : null, proxy=null, job.clubUsername, clubPassword, job.startTime, job.endTime, job.date, job.courseList, job.id)
            // await console.log(member=job.member?job.member : null, proxy=null, job.clubUsername, clubPassword, job.startTime, job.endTime, job.courseList, job.id)
        }
    }
    return
    
}

module.exports = { runBot }
```

This is the error I get when I try to run the imported function.

```
c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\utils\cron\createCron.js:32
        await runBot([job])
              ^

TypeError: runBot is not a function
    at Job.job (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\utils\cron\createCron.js:32:15)
    at Job.invoke (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\Job.js:171:15)
    at c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\Invocation.js:268:28
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\Invocation.js:228:7)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Job instance at:
    at c:\Users\carjames\OneDrive - Cisco\Documents\Code\Barton-Bot-Backend\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\Invocation.js:277:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Node.js v17.6.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I guess the first question on everyone's mind will be: "is `runBot` actually a function?"

Comment: Yes see my latest edit @robertklep

Comment: You're not showing how you import it. Also, for fun, add a `console.log(runBot)` _before_ `schedule.scheduleJob()`.

Comment: I did it, and it comes back as undefined, but I don't know why @robertklep

Comment: I also added my import statment

Comment: It's likely caused by [a circular dependency between your files](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles) (for example: file A requires file B which requires file C which requires file A). A quick fix would be to move the `require()` _into_ the `createCron` function.

Comment: Ok I suspected that but In the two files where these functions are there are no imports going both ways.

Comment: IE functions coming from createCron file arent imported into runBot file or vice versa